# Construct a defective matrix using scaling and rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having read some material regarding the properties of defective matrix and methods to repair it (ie finding generalized eigenvalue).. I am wondering if there are ways to construct a defective matrix through combination of rotation and scaling?

Comment: I don't have an answer but looking at the Special Euclidean group might be something you could check out since rotations and scaling correspond to elements of SE(n) with a particular restriction on the last column. You can find some eigenvalue/vector properties of SO(n) - which correspond to just rotations - [here](http://files.umwblogs.org/blogs.dir/4710/files/2010/10/honors_triola.pdf) to start with.

Comment: can shearing transformation be decomposed into variable rotation and scaling (similar question since defective matrix describes shearing transformation...

Comment: I don't think you can decompose a shear matrix into rotation and scaling because shearing intrinsically does something that rotation and scaling alone does not achieve.

Comment: by scaling are you referring to constant scaling (multiply a constant?) and by rotation are you referring rotation by a constant angle? Intuitive.. any points on a R2 place can be reached by a scaling and rotation? Am I not correct?

Answer (score 0):

If by "scaling" you mean a multiple of the identity matrix, then this is not possible. Such a matrix commutes with any rotation, so given a combination of scaling and rotation, you can do the rotations first and then the scaling; that is, you will have $\lambda R$ for some real number $\lambda$ and real orthogonal matrix $R$. Then $R$ is diagonalizable over the complex numbers [(see wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Matrix_properties). If $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of eigenvectors of $R$, then these are also eigenvectors of $\lambda R$.

If you allow scaling by different factors along each axis (ie diagonal matrices) then there are examples. For instance

$$
  \begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}3+2\sqrt{2}&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
  =  \begin{bmatrix}2+3/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\ 2+3/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
has a repeat eigenvalue $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: by multiple do you specifically mean a constant multiple?

Comment: Also by rotation, are you referring to a rotation of a constant angle?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author Yes in the first paragraph I am interpreting scaling as $\lambda I$ for some number $\lambda$. I would define a rotation to be an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1. This includes rotation by any angle around any axis.

Comment: @if the scaling factor is dependant on the rotation angle, (it is still linear transform), can you still say the construction is impossible?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I'm not sure what you mean; could you give an example matrix?